# ics file is not downloadable by the web browser

Tags: c#, .net, icalendar

The Ics file is not downloaded by the browser, I have used [iCal.NET](https://github.com/rianjs/ical.net) to generate ics file and the code is ok but the ics file is not downloadable. How can I download it as an attachment? I mean How to make .ics file as downloadable so I can download it to my disk and then open it by Outlook to add it to the calendar.

My code:

```
var calendar = new Ical.Net.Calendar();

calendar.Events.Add(new Event
    {
        Class = "PUBLIC",
        Summary = Summary,
        Created = new CalDateTime(DateTime.Now),
        Description = title,
        Start = new CalDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(EventStart)),
        End = new CalDateTime(Convert.ToDateTime(EventEnd)),
        Sequence = 0,
        Uid = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),
        Location = Location,
    });

var serializer = new CalendarSerializer(new SerializationContext());
var serializedCalendar = serializer.SerializeToString(calendar);
var bytesCalendar = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(serializedCalendar);

return File(bytesCalendar, "text/calendar", "event.ics");
```

In the browser response I am getting the following which is correct:

```
BEGIN:VCALENDAR
PRODID:-//github.com/rianjs/ical.net//NONSGML ical.net 2.2//EN
VERSION:2.0
BEGIN:VEVENT
CLASS:PUBLIC
CREATED:20190403T191521
DESCRIPTION:Inspection of property: 6 Dight Avenue Balwyn North 3104
DTEND:20190413T110000
DTSTAMP:20190403T111521Z
DTSTART:20190413T103000
LOCATION:-37.797534\, 145.079921
SEQUENCE:0
SUMMARY:Inspection of property: 6 Dight Avenue Balwyn North 3104
UID:d977d4c7-2a0d-453e-940f-d7313e35b197
END:VEVENT
END:VCALENDAR
```

Comment: Please explain what you mean by "is not downloaded by the browser". What happens? Do you have any error messages? As it's not clear what's actually going wrong, please take the time to update your question with more information, then I'm sure you'll get more helpful response.

Comment: I agree that looks like it should be doing *something*; so: what actually happens? if you fire up "Fiddler", for example - what is the actual http response here? Do the headers and content look right? i.e. does it have the content-type and disposition that you've specified? and is the response body the ics data?

Comment: Please show the HTTP headers of the response. You can view these in the browser's dev tools.

Comment: Here is the header response:                HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 485
Content-Type: text/calendar; charset=utf-8
Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=CalendarItem_6 Dight Avenue Balwyn North 3104.ics.ics
X-SourceFiles: =?UTF-8?B?QzpcVXNlcnNcQXN1c1xEZXNrdG9wXEF1c3RyYWxpYV9Tb3VyY2VcQXVzdHJhbGlhXFBQUS5XZWJcU2VhcmNoXENyZWF0ZUlDU0ZpbGVc?=

Answer (score 0):

Here is my solution that worked for me:

```
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

        //start the calendar item
        sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        sb.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        sb.AppendLine("PRODID:propertyqueen.com");
        sb.AppendLine("CALSCALE:GREGORIAN");
        sb.AppendLine("METHOD:PUBLISH");

        //create a time zone if needed, TZID to be used in the event itself
        sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VTIMEZONE");
        sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:STANDARD");

        sb.AppendLine("TZID:Australia/Sydney");
        sb.AppendLine("TZOFFSETTO:+1000");
        sb.AppendLine("TZOFFSETFROM:+1000");

        sb.AppendLine("END:STANDARD");
        sb.AppendLine("END:VTIMEZONE");

        //add the event
        sb.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");

        //without timezones
        sb.AppendLine("DTSTART:" + EventStartDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm00"));
        sb.AppendLine("DTEND:" + EventEndDateTime.ToString("yyyyMMddTHHmm00"));
        sb.AppendLine("SUMMARY:" + Summary + "");
        sb.AppendLine("LOCATION:" + Location + "");
        sb.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:" + Description + "");
        sb.AppendLine("PRIORITY:3");
        sb.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        sb.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");


        //send the calendar item to the browser
        Response.ClearHeaders();
        Response.Clear();
        Response.Buffer = true;
        Response.ContentType = "text/calendar";
        Response.AddHeader("content-length", sb.Length.ToString());
        Response.AddHeader("content-disposition", "attachment;filename=" + FileName);

        Response.Write(sb.ToString());
        Response.Flush();
        Response.End();

        var bytes = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(sb.ToString());
        return File(bytes, "text/calendar", FileName);
```